# Rails: download .to_pdf stuck on old revision of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin

I have a rails app and stuck on a problem when trying to create a download link to some dynamic generated data.
I've placed a `.to_pdf` method in my `Folha` model. And on controller `folhas_controller.rb`:

```
def show
    nome = "#{@folha.nome_do_mes}-#{@folha.ano}-#{DateTime.now.to_i}"
    @folha = Folha.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        pdf = @folha.to_pdf(view_context)
        send_data pdf.render, filename: "#{nome}.pdf", type: "application/pdf"
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue is that the `.to_pdf` method is executed only the first time i click the link. For  all other clicks it gives me the same file, no matter if my object was updated.
I dont know where in my stack this is ocurring. 
It only happens in production. Im using Rails 3.2.6 on Thin 1.4.1 deployed to heroku.
Please help =)

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround, pretty sure its not the proper way:
`routes.rb`

```
  resources :folhas do
    resources :servicos
  end

  match 'exportar/:id/:dummy' => 'folhas#show', as: "exportar"
```

and then on the view:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('pdf_small.png'), exportar_path(id: folha.id, dummy: DateTime.now.to_i, format: 'pdf'), class: 'item' %>
```

that way a different link is placed each time the view is rendered.